# C# static member `System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string)'

Tags: c#, methods, static

error CS0176: Static member `System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Why doesnt this code work

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace main
{
    class firstreq
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.240.1");  
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest2.Create("https://192.168.240.1/getname");  
                HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest2.GetResponse();
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried to remove the static but it does not work, any solutions would be cool, thanks

Comment: In `HttpWebRequest webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest2.Create("https://192.168.240.1/getname"); `, the second `webRequest2` should be `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`WebRequest.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-5.0) is a static method, and as such, can only be referenced on the type name (`WebRequest`) and not via instances of the class.

Try doing:

```
 HttpWebRequest webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.240.1/getname");
```